# Image from byte array

Tags: vb.net, image

I need to render an image in an `ObjectListView` column, so I set an `ImageRenderer` that accepts a byte array and use this code to change it into an image

```
image = Image.FromStream(stream);
```

That said, I need to extract an icon from an exe file, convert it into a byte array so that `ObjectListView` can render it.
Here is the code I use:

```
Using ms = New MemoryStream()
    Dim imageIn = Icon.ExtractAssociatedIcon(exe_path)
    imageIn.Save(ms)
    Return ms.ToArray()
End Using
```

Problem is that image is rendered with wrong colors (like if it was 8bpp).
So I tried to use this code to find the problem:

```
Using ms = New MemoryStream()
    Dim imageIn = Icon.ExtractAssociatedIcon(exe_path)
    imageIn.Save(ms)

    Dim bmp = imageIn.ToBitmap()
    bmp.Save("img1.bmp")
    Using mt As New MemoryStream(ms.ToArray())
        Dim img = Image.FromStream(mt)
        img.Save("img2.bmp")
    End Using
End Using
```

In this scenario, `img1.bmp` is correct (bitmap with real colors), while `img2.bmp` has wrong colors; so either `ms.ToArray()` or `Image.FromStream` corrupt the image.

**SOLUTION:**
Solution given by Steven Doggart solves problem of colors, but rendered image is not "transparent".
A possible solution is making the bitmap transparent and passing a PNG format to the array

```
Using ms = New MemoryStream()
    Dim bmp = Icon.ExtractAssociatedIcon(exe_path).ToBitmap()
    bmp.MakeTransparent(bmp.GetPixel(0, 0))
    bmp.Save(ms, ImageFormat.Png)

    Using mt As New MemoryStream(ms.ToArray())
        Dim img = Image.FromStream(mt)
        img.Save("img2.bmp")
    End Using
End Using
```

Comment: It would seem to me that the difference between `img1.bmp` and `img2.bmp` is not how you read/wrote the stream, but rather how you generated the byte array.  If I'm reading your code correctly, `img1.bmp` is generated by calling `Bitmap.Save` whereas `img2.bmp` is generated by calling `Icon.Save`.  So, one is a bitmap and the other is an icon.  Those are two very different data formats.

Comment: Yes @Steven, sure, but ObjectListView internally uses Image.FromStream(byte_array) and I cannot change it; so I need to read the icon, convert that to a byte array that's readable and renderable correctly from ObjectListView...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are saving an `Icon` to a byte array, but then you are loading it from that byte array directly into an `Image`.  `Icon` objects are not stored in the same byte-array format as `Image` objects.  `Icon` objects can contain multiple images of different sizes and color depths whereas `Image` objects can only contain one.  Also, `Icon` objects accept the alpha channel (transparency) whereas `Image` objects do not.

When you save the `Icon` to the byte array, you should first extract the desired bitmap from it, like this:

```
Using ms = New MemoryStream()
    Dim imageIn = Icon.ExtractAssociatedIcon(exe_path)
    imageIn.ToBitmap().Save(ms, ImageFormat.Bmp)
    Return ms.ToArray()
End Using
```

Comment: Thanks Steven, you're right, but be careful I can't use your syntax; try changing it to `imageIn.ToBitmap().Save(ms, ImageFormat.Bmp)`. Rendered bitmap anyway is not transparent... need to solve this too, but we're on the good way!

Comment: If fixed my example to specify the format.  Thanks.

Comment: Transparency problem remains: read my edited post please. Thank you!